# I have tried to get random variations from the tags but it doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to mimic the prototype
https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/zYxvJmP?editors=0011

But my work loops strangely , it can't run all tags and when I click the start button it only flash the final one.
https://codepen.io/penny289/pen/VwWGdXw?editors=0010

```js
function randomPick(){
    var times=30; 
    var tags=$('.tag');
    function randomSelectTag(){
      return tags[Math.floor(Math.random()*tags.length)];
      console.log(tags)
      
    };
    console.log(tags)
    function highlight(tag){
      tag.classList.add('highlight');
    };
    function unhighlight(tag){
      tag.classList.remove('highlight');
    };
    var result = randomSelectTag()
    console.log(result)
    var interval =setInterval(function(){
      highlight(result);
      setTimeout(function(){
        unhighlight(result);
      },100);
    },100);
    setInterval(function(){
      clearInterval(interval)
      setTimeout(function(){
        highlight(result)
      },100);
    },times*100);
  };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed 2 lines:

- move `randomSelectTag()` into `setInterval`
- increase the timeout of `var interval` from `100` to `300` to let the animation is better.

**Your origin code:**

```
var result = randomSelectTag()
    console.log(result)
    var interval =setInterval(function(){
      highlight(result);
      setTimeout(function(){
        unhighlight(result);
      },100);
    },100);
```

**Fixed version:**

```
var result;
    var interval =setInterval(function(){
      result = randomSelectTag();   // move this line into setInterval
      highlight(result);
      setTimeout(function(){
        unhighlight(result);
      },100);
    },300);   // increase this time because the unhighlight timeout is 100, you should increase to let see the different.
```

**Live demo:**

https://codepen.io/tuandaodev/pen/XWgoRBe